# Retrieve multiple tasks in an Automation via API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, automation

We can make a Retrieve call on an Automation object and if it contains only one Task get some details on that task. But, when there is more than one Task, the call does not return any information. Basically, we're trying to use the API to describe an automation, the tasks and activities. Has anyone solved this? Thanks!

Automation with one task: https://d.pr/i/eQaryb

SOAP Call:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-32259181" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>[username[</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">[password]</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>Automation</ObjectType>
                <Properties>*</Properties>
                <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                    <Property>ProgramID</Property>
                    <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                    <Value>9bee2fc2-38db-4aa0-806c-a618850edd5f</Value>
                </Filter>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

SOAP Response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <soap:Header>
      <wsa:Action>RetrieveResponse</wsa:Action>
      <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:179a77cd-12e9-44b8-91bd-c7fe24eacb91</wsa:MessageID>
      <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:555c9794-a6ba-4f56-be00-2439a20eaca7</wsa:RelatesTo>
      <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
      <wsse:Security>
         <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-02868ad0-c876-40f2-ac88-5549d30a57e1">
            <wsu:Created>2019-02-27T02:46:18Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2019-02-27T02:51:18Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
         <RequestID>6780b1c7-83cc-4849-8cac-21dbef37678a</RequestID>
         <Results xsi:type="Automation">
            <Client/>
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
            <PartnerProperties>
               <Name>AutomationType</Name>
               <Value>scheduled</Value>
            </PartnerProperties>
            <CreatedDate>2018-12-03T18:58:38.61</CreatedDate>
            <ModifiedDate>2019-02-26T12:22:45.607</ModifiedDate>
            <ObjectID>9bee2fc2-38db-4aa0-806c-a618850edd5f</ObjectID>
            <CustomerKey>9a621fe5-afa5-55af-1aa1-04b8581933cd</CustomerKey>
            <IsPlatformObject>false</IsPlatformObject>
            <Name>KM_Test</Name>
            <Description>Kevin testing Automation Studio functions.</Description>
            <AutomationTasks>
               <AutomationTask>
                  <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <Activities>
                     <Activity>
                        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <CreatedDate>2019-02-26T12:22:45.45</CreatedDate>
                        <ObjectID>ef5c5f0c-095f-4480-953a-f69e8db9f050</ObjectID>
                        <CustomerKey>c16acd5a-37c3-459c-ba7d-54816ff9ef6b</CustomerKey>
                        <Name>Only Influencers We re Hiring</Name>
                        <Description/>
                        <IsActive>true</IsActive>
                        <Definition>
                           <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                           <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                           <CustomerKey>c16acd5a-37c3-459c-ba7d-54816ff9ef6b</CustomerKey>
                        </Definition>
                        <Sequence>0</Sequence>
                     </Activity>
                  </Activities>
               </AutomationTask>
            </AutomationTasks>
            <IsActive>true</IsActive>
            <Status>2</Status>
            <AutomationType>scheduled</AutomationType>
            <LastRunInstanceID/>
            <CreatedBy>11049166</CreatedBy>
            <CategoryID>1329642</CategoryID>
            <LastRunTime>2018-12-03T19:07:01.487</LastRunTime>
            <LastSaveDate>2019-02-26T12:22:45.117</LastSaveDate>
            <ModifiedBy>-1000</ModifiedBy>
            <RecurrenceID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</RecurrenceID>
         </Results>
      </RetrieveResponseMsg>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Automation with two tasks: https://d.pr/i/Ef9iZV
SOAP Call:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-32259181" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>[username[</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">[password]</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
                <ObjectType>Automation</ObjectType>
                <Properties>*</Properties>
                <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                    <Property>ProgramID</Property>
                    <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                    <Value>9bee2fc2-38db-4aa0-806c-a618850edd5f</Value>
                </Filter>
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

SOAP Response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <soap:Header>
      <wsa:Action>RetrieveResponse</wsa:Action>
      <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:7bcf452a-99d4-47b7-bd14-cc5e4b6ac977</wsa:MessageID>
      <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:1671ea39-0bbc-45b9-ade3-2c16af93589a</wsa:RelatesTo>
      <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
      <wsse:Security>
         <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-5e840af2-e3c2-4cd8-9ddd-c7c6ce37aabd">
            <wsu:Created>2019-02-27T02:48:33Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2019-02-27T02:53:33Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
         <RequestID>e17f4162-df93-43fc-9d29-7f36572bd1bf</RequestID>
         <Results xsi:type="Automation">
            <Client/>
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
            <PartnerProperties>
               <Name>AutomationType</Name>
               <Value>scheduled</Value>
            </PartnerProperties>
            <CreatedDate>2018-12-03T18:58:38.61</CreatedDate>
            <ModifiedDate>2019-02-26T20:48:26.65</ModifiedDate>
            <ObjectID>9bee2fc2-38db-4aa0-806c-a618850edd5f</ObjectID>
            <CustomerKey>9a621fe5-afa5-55af-1aa1-04b8581933cd</CustomerKey>
            <IsPlatformObject>false</IsPlatformObject>
            <Name>KM_Test</Name>
            <Description>Kevin testing Automation Studio functions.</Description>
            <AutomationTasks/>
            <IsActive>true</IsActive>
            <Status>1</Status>
            <AutomationType>scheduled</AutomationType>
            <LastRunInstanceID/>
            <CreatedBy>11049166</CreatedBy>
            <CategoryID>1329642</CategoryID>
            <LastRunTime>2018-12-03T19:07:01.487</LastRunTime>
            <LastSaveDate>2019-02-26T20:48:26.277</LastSaveDate>
            <ModifiedBy>-1000</ModifiedBy>
            <RecurrenceID>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</RecurrenceID>
         </Results>
      </RetrieveResponseMsg>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Thanks!

Comment: you need get multiple task from one automation am i right ?

Comment: Yes, we want to retrieve multiple tasks from one automation.

Comment: You'll probably need to retrieve the AutomationTask objects in another call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve multiple tasks for an automation by first retrieving the `ObjectID` for your automation, then filtering on that when you retrieve the `Activity` object, as follows:

1. Retrieve your `ObjectID`:

   ```
   <Body>
       <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
           <RetrieveRequest>
               <ObjectType>Program</ObjectType>
               <Properties>Program.ObjectID</Properties>
               <Properties>Name</Properties>
               <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                   <Property>Name</Property>
                   <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                   <Value>[my automation name]</Value>
               </Filter>
           </RetrieveRequest>
       </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </Body>
   ```
2. Retrieve your activities, filtering on your `ObjectID`:

   ```
   <Body>
       <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
           <RetrieveRequest>
               <ObjectType>Activity</ObjectType>
               <Properties>Name</Properties>
               <Properties>Description</Properties>
               <Properties>ObjectID</Properties>
               <Properties>Step</Properties>
               <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                   <Property>Program.ObjectID</Property>
                   <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                   <Value>[objectid from step 1]</Value>
               </Filter>
           </RetrieveRequest>
       </RetrieveRequestMsg>
   </Body>
   ```

Curiously, it seems that both the `Program` and `Activity` object types are undocumented at the moment.

Comment: +1! Where/how did you find the object properties for Program and Activity?

Comment: I believe both of those objects are being phased out as they were for the original 'classic' programs, prior to Automation Studio - which is why they are undocumented. They DO still work now, but I just worry that they may not be available for much longer. Do you happen to know a way utilizing the new objects? Any insights you can provide there will definitely secure the bounty for you.

Comment: Did some searching on my own and found that the 'AutomationTask', 'AutomationActivity', etc. are supposed to be what replaces the program versions, but they are not allowing any methods yet. If you remove the 'Automation' from these objects and use (as you showed) `Program.` on the ObjectID (which can be gathered via the Automation object as well) it will work. So in theory, once these objects allow methods, all you will need to do is insert 'Automation' in front of the object and change `Program.` to 'Automation.`.

Comment: Also - I believe it is `Sequence`, not `Step`. Great Answer @NickKroehl. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Automation and Program both have the same retrievable properties.  I'm working on a WSProxy prototype of this and I've found the relationships between the objects to be this: Program -> Task (where Task.Program.ObjectID = Program.ObjectID) -> Activity (where Activity.Task.ObjectID = Task.ObjectID).  Tasks represent the columns in Automation Studio. Activities are the objects in each column.

Comment: I'm stuck relating the Activity objects back to the object types (e.g. query, script, etc.)

Comment: Yeah seems all relevant properties are not retrievable. =(

Comment: @AdamSpriggs that's exactly right. To get _some_ of the activity detail we usually do a try-catch on each type of retrievable activity (import, query, user-initiated send), but this technique only gets you so far.

Comment: Thank you @NickKroehl – that has been the most help. Similar to Gortonington, Adam-Spriggs,  we've struggled to get any of the other detail, particularly the type of Activity. However, at least now we can "see" inside an Automation. I wonder when we'll be able to use methods against these Automation objects and the most interesting fields will become retrievable. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

To provide some small level of documentation on the undocumented objects @NickKroehl provided, I wanted to list the Describe results I got on each of them.

The 'Name' tag is the Property you will need to include in your API call. Make sure to note the 'IsRetrievable' and 'IsUpdatable' tags to see if available for your method types.

I am only including Program, Activity and Task Objects - but there is also the following objects available:

1. ActivityInstance
2. TaskInstance
3. ProgramInstance

**Program**

```
       <ObjectType>Program</ObjectType>
        <Properties>
            <Name>ObjectID</Name>
            <DataType>String</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Name</Name>
            <DataType>String</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <MaxLength>200</MaxLength>
            <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Description</Name>
            <DataType>String</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <MaxLength>200</MaxLength>
            <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Schedule.ID</Name>
            <DataType>Int32</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>CustomerKey</Name>
            <DataType>String</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <MaxLength>200</MaxLength>
            <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Client.ID</Name>
            <DataType>Int64</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>IsActive</Name>
            <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>CreatedDate</Name>
            <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Client.CreatedBy</Name>
            <DataType>Int64</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>ModifiedDate</Name>
            <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Client.ModifiedBy</Name>
            <DataType>Int64</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Status</Name>
            <DataType>Int32</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Client.EnterpriseID</Name>
            <DataType>Int64</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Schedule</Name>
            <DataType>ScheduleDefinition</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Tasks</Name>
            <DataType>Task[]</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>CategoryID</Name>
            <DataType>String</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>ProgramSource</Name>
            <DataType>ProgramSource</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Notifications</Name>
            <DataType>ProgramNotification[]</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>ScheduledTime</Name>
            <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>AutomationType</Name>
            <DataType>String</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>InteractionObjectID</Name>
            <DataType>String</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Keyword</Name>
            <DataType>String</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Client</Name>
            <DataType>ClientID</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>PartnerKey</Name>
            <DataType>String</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>PartnerProperties</Name>
            <DataType>APIProperty[]</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>ID</Name>
            <DataType>Int32</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Owner</Name>
            <DataType>Owner</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>CorrelationID</Name>
            <DataType>String</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>ObjectState</Name>
            <DataType>String</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>IsPlatformObject</Name>
            <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
        </Properties>
```

**Activity**

```
        <ObjectType>Activity</ObjectType>
        <Properties>
            <Name>ObjectID</Name>
            <DataType>String</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Program.ObjectID</Name>
            <DataType>Guid</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Task.ObjectID</Name>
            <DataType>Guid</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Sequence</Name>
            <DataType>Int32</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Name</Name>
            <DataType>String</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <MaxLength>200</MaxLength>
            <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Description</Name>
            <DataType>String</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <MaxLength>200</MaxLength>
            <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Definition.ID</Name>
            <DataType>Int32</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Definition.ObjectID</Name>
            <DataType>Guid</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>PartnerAPIObjectTypeID</Name>
            <DataType>Int32</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>CustomerKey</Name>
            <DataType>String</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <MaxLength>200</MaxLength>
            <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Client.ID</Name>
            <DataType>Int64</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Definition</Name>
            <DataType>APIObject</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>IsActive</Name>
            <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>CreatedDate</Name>
            <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Client.CreatedBy</Name>
            <DataType>Int64</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>ModifiedDate</Name>
            <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Client.ModifiedBy</Name>
            <DataType>Int64</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Client.EnterpriseID</Name>
            <DataType>Int64</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
            <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Program</Name>
            <DataType>Program</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Task</Name>
            <DataType>Task</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>SerializedObject</Name>
            <DataType>String</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>ActivityObject</Name>
            <DataType>APIObject</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Client</Name>
            <DataType>ClientID</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>PartnerKey</Name>
            <DataType>String</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>PartnerProperties</Name>
            <DataType>APIProperty[]</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>ID</Name>
            <DataType>Int32</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>Owner</Name>
            <DataType>Owner</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>CorrelationID</Name>
            <DataType>String</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>ObjectState</Name>
            <DataType>String</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
        </Properties>
        <Properties>
            <Name>IsPlatformObject</Name>
            <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
            <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
            <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
        </Properties>
```

**Task**

```
                <ObjectType>Task</ObjectType>
                <Properties>
                    <Name>ObjectID</Name>
                    <DataType>String</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <Name>Program.ObjectID</Name>
                    <DataType>Guid</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <Name>Name</Name>
                    <DataType>String</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <MaxLength>255</MaxLength>
                    <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <Name>Description</Name>
                    <DataType>String</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <MaxLength>255</MaxLength>
                    <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <Name>Sequence</Name>
                    <DataType>Int32</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <Name>Client.ID</Name>
                    <DataType>Int64</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <Name>Client.UserID</Name>
                    <DataType>Int64</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <Name>CreatedDate</Name>
                    <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <Name>Client.CreatedBy</Name>
                    <DataType>Int64</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <Name>ModifiedDate</Name>
                    <DataType>DateTime</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <Name>Client.ModifiedBy</Name>
                    <DataType>Int64</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <Name>Client.EnterpriseID</Name>
                    <DataType>Int64</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>true</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>true</IsRetrievable>
                    <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <Name>TaskType</Name>
                    <DataType>String</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <Name>Program</Name>
                    <DataType>Program</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <Name>Activities</Name>
                    <DataType>Activity[]</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <Name>Client</Name>
                    <DataType>ClientID</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <Name>PartnerKey</Name>
                    <DataType>String</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <Name>PartnerProperties</Name>
                    <DataType>APIProperty[]</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <Name>ID</Name>
                    <DataType>Int32</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <Name>CustomerKey</Name>
                    <DataType>String</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <Name>Owner</Name>
                    <DataType>Owner</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <Name>CorrelationID</Name>
                    <DataType>String</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <Name>ObjectState</Name>
                    <DataType>String</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
                <Properties>
                    <Name>IsPlatformObject</Name>
                    <DataType>Boolean</DataType>
                    <IsUpdatable>false</IsUpdatable>
                    <IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>
                </Properties>
```