# Associating Email Sends with Automation Activity via API

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, api, automation

This is a continuation of this question: [Retrieve multiple tasks in an Automation via API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251844/retrieve-multiple-tasks-in-an-automation-via-api)

Now that we have been able to retrieve the Activities within an Automation, we would like to take it one step further to see if we can get the email details from within that Activity.

The assumption we are using is that we can use the `Activity.ObjectID` as the filter to associate it with the email. However, there are a lot of email-related objects in the API are we aren't sure which one would be associated with the Activity.

Does anyone know which Email/Send object we should be trying to get and if our `Activity.ObjectID` assumption is correct for the filter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to really be able to tell if something is an email or any other interaction type from the return in Activity/Tasks which makes this more difficult.

Your best bet to finding the Emails inside the automation is to take the `Deinition.ObjectID` of the Activity and use that in another API call to the object [EmailSendDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/emailsenddefinition.htm). This will return the information relating to the email that is used in that activity - if it exists.

Call to Activity Object:

```
  <RetrieveRequest>
        <ObjectType>Activity</ObjectType>
        <Properties>Definition.ObjectID</Properties>
        <Properties>Name</Properties>
        <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
        <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
            <Property>Program.ObjectID</Property>
            <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
            <Value>{{yourProgramID}}</Value>
        </Filter>
     </RetrieveRequest>
```

You then that the `Definition.ObjectID` and do the following call:

```
     <RetrieveRequest>
        <ObjectType>EmailSendDefinition</ObjectType>
        <Properties>ObjectID</Properties>
        <Properties>Name</Properties>
        <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
        <Properties>DynamicEmailSubject</Properties>
        <Properties>EmailSubject</Properties>
        <Properties>SendDefinitionList</Properties>
        <Properties>CategoryID</Properties>
        ....
        <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
           <Property>ObjectID</Property>
           <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
           <Value>{{yourDefinition.ObjectID}}</Value>
        </Filter>
     </RetrieveRequest>
```

On those that are not Email Interactions that you push there should return empty results, which you can then use to filter out only the Email interactions.

Same theory can be used on other interaction definition objects, e.g. `QueryDefinition`, `FilterDefinition`, etc.