# Identify the Type of an Automation Activity using SSJS WSProxy

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, ssjs

I'm trying to create an API call that will return the SQL Code from all Query Activities within an given Automation.
Using the information provided in this question [Retrieve multiple tasks in an Automation via API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/251844/retrieve-multiple-tasks-in-an-automation-via-api/252341#252341), I have been able to develop the following SSJS on a Cloud Page:

```
var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var cols1 = ['ObjectID'];
var Program = api.retrieve('Program', cols1, { Property : 'CustomerKey', SimpleOperator : 'equals', Value : '##automationCustomerKey##' });
var objectid = Program.Results[0].ObjectID;

var cols2 = ['ObjectID','Name'];
var Activity = api.retrieve('Activity', cols2, { Property : 'Program.ObjectID', SimpleOperator : 'equals', Value : objectid });
Write(Stringify(Activity));
```

This successfully outputs a list of all the Automation Activities in the specified Automation.

From here I want to identify which of the Activities in the Automation are the "SQL Query" type, and call the "[QueryDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/querydefinition.htm)" API to get the "QueryText" Value (the SQL Code).

However there is no clear way to identify what TYPE of activity each of them are; SQL Query, SSJS Script, Send Email, etc.

The following table corresponds to the "PartnerAPIObjectID" values that match each activity type:

> 42 User-initiated Email
>   43 Import Definition
>   45 Group Definition
>   53 File Transfer Activity
>   73 Data Extract Activity
>   84 Report Activity
>   300 Query Activity
>   303 Filter Activity
>   423 Server Side Javascript Activity
>   425 ELT Activity
>   427 Build Audience Activity
>   467 Program Wait
>   724 Mobile Automation List Refresh Instance
>   725 MobileConnect Message Instance
>   726 Mobile File Import Instance
>   733 InteractionStudio
>   736 MobilePush Message Object Instance
>   749 Interaction Studio Event
>   756 Interaction Studio Date Event
>   771 Salesforce Send Activiy
>   783 GroupConnect
>   1010 Thunderhead Transfer Activity
>   1101 Interaction Studio Decision Activity
>   1701 PredictiveIntelligenceRecommendationActivity
>   **Source: Salesforce Tier 2 Technical Support, Oct 2019**

As above (and in the linked question), the "Activity" endpoint does not seem to have any reference to the "Activity Type" or a "PartnerAPIObjectID" field.

I'm looking for any information on how to achieve my goal - getting the SQL code of all activities within a given Automation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't mind using an undocumented REST endpoint, you could use the `/automation/v1/automations/{{objID}}` endpoint.

```
GET /automation/v1/automations/{{yourAutoObjId}} 
Host: {{subdomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Authorization: Bearer {{authToken}}
Content-Type: application/json
```

This will return all the steps/activities inside the automation including ID, objectTypeId and Name.

The objectTypeID will relate to your 'PartnerAPIObjectID' values.  From there you can use the corresponding REST endpoints or SOAP objects to gather the content of each step.

Example Response:

```
{
    "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "name": "my_Automation",
    "description": "",
    "key": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "typeId": 1,
    "type": "scheduled",
    "statusId": 2,
    "status": "Ready",
    "categoryId": XXXXX,
    "lastRunTime": "2019-10-21T14:57:00.58",
    "lastRunInstanceId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "schedule": {
        "scheduleStatus": "none"
    },
    "steps": [
        {
            "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "name": "",
            "step": 1,
            "activities": [
                {
                    "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    "name": "Salesforce Send",
                    "activityObjectId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    "objectTypeId": 771,
                    "displayOrder": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    "name": "Query Activity",
                    "activityObjectId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    "objectTypeId": 300,
                    "displayOrder": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    "name": "Refresh Group",
                    "activityObjectId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    "objectTypeId": 45,
                    "displayOrder": 3
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "name": "",
            "step": 2,
            "activities": [
                {
                    "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    "name": "Data Extract",
                    "activityObjectId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    "objectTypeId": 73,
                    "displayOrder": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    "name": "File Transfer",
                    "activityObjectId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    "objectTypeId": 53,
                    "displayOrder": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    "name": "Data Factory Utility",
                    "activityObjectId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    "objectTypeId": 425,
                    "displayOrder": 3
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "name": "",
            "step": 3,
            "activities": [
                {
                    "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    "name": "Filter Activity",
                    "activityObjectId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    "objectTypeId": 303,
                    "displayOrder": 1,
                    "targetDataExtensions": [
                        {
                            "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                            "name": "DEName",
                            "key": "DEKey",
                            "description": "",
                            "rowCount": 3
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    "name": "Fire Event",
                    "activityObjectId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    "objectTypeId": 749,
                    "displayOrder": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my list of ObjectTypeIds:

```
Salesforce Send
"objectTypeId": 771

Query Activity
"objectTypeId": 300

Data Extract
"objectTypeId": 73

File Transfer
"objectTypeId": 53

Filter Activity
"objectTypeId": 303

Fire Event
"objectTypeId": 749

Import File
"objectTypeId": 43

Script Activity
"objectTypeId": 423

Guided Send
"objectTypeId": 42

Wait Activity
"objectTypeId": 467

Verification Activity
"objectTypeId": 1000

Refresh Group
"objectTypeId": 45

Data Factory Utility
"objectTypeId": 425

Send SMS
"objectTypeId": 725

Import Mobile Contacts
"objectTypeId": 726

Refresh Mobile Filtered List
"objectTypeId": 724

Send GroupConnect
"objectTypeId": 783

Report Definition
"objectTypeId": 84

Send Push
"objectTypeId": 736
```

Comment: Thanks Gortonington - I'll check your response shortly! Any chance you have a source for the undocumented SOAP/REST end points; this seems to be a common theme..

Comment: I have not really had the time to put something together to post up my findings so far. Best I can say for quick reference is to do a GET to the 'discovery' endpoints (/rest).  For example: `/automation/v1/rest` or `/messaging/v1/rest` and that should list all (including undocumented) endpoints in that 'subsection'.

Comment: For those interested, the objectTypeIds can be found by inspecting HTML source for drag-able activity icons on the Automation page.  That'll list only what's enabled in your BU.