# Retrieve Automation detailed information and setting

Tags: marketing-cloud

My objective is to retrieve the details and the configuration setup of the automation activities (e.g. Extract Type, DECustomer Key, File Transfer details, File Action, File Naming, Transfer setting) for a list of activities to perform regular checking. It would be very manual checking every activities and time consuming.

I have tried the SSJS scripts from Ivan's blog (https://ampscript.xyz/how-tos/how-to-use-wsproxy-to-work-with-automations-in-server-side-javascript/#activities-status) to retrieve automation activity details. However, most of the info returned are not useful. Not sure the info I mentioned could be retrieved?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check the answer to [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/283002/identify-the-type-of-an-automation-activity-using-ssjs-wsproxy?rq=1). It details using an undocumented rest endpoint to retrieve the activities in an automation which returns the activity object ID as well as the object type ID, you'd then use the corresponding endpoint to retrieve the activity details based on the object type ID. That said it also looks like the SSJS in the question also gives a list of PartnerAPIObjectID so you could do the same thing using the SSJS rather than the undocumented rest end point.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.